# How can I automatically include the sections from an \includepdf in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, pdfpages

I am writing a thesis, and need to include a couple of papers in the end as appendices, using \includepdf{}. The thesis office requires that all the sections of the papers be listed in the table of contents of the thesis. That is, the paper is in its own chapter, and each section of the included paper should be listed in the Table of Contents as a section in that chapter. I have an example where this is done using commands like this:

```
\FPeval{\IntroPage}{clip(\thepage+1)}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\numberline {\thechapter.1}Introduction}{\IntroPage}}

\FPeval{\PreliminariesPage}{clip(\thepage+3)}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\numberline {\thechapter.2}Preliminaries and Notation}{\PreliminariesPage}}
```

This requires one to manually find the page numbers of all the sections. I don't really like this solution. Is there any way to do this automatically? I have the .tex source of the papers if that helps.

Comment: (Is there anything better than the requirements imposed by thesis offices?!) Can you really include a multipage PDF and have it write to the TOC of another file? How on earth would it 'know' the meaning of the pictures it is including? I have heard the term 'automagically' before, but this would be next level!  Consider too that the papers are 'fixed' so its not like they'll change as long as you can set the 'start page' once. Just devise a macro like \addsectotoc{<section level>}{<title>}{<relative page number>}`. Seem like it would take about ten minutes to do this....

Comment: If you have the tex sources why don't you input them into your tex document and get consistent formatting and tables of contents instead of including them via includepdf (in which case tex has no information at all about their contents)

Comment: @jon I was hoping that one of the files produced by latex would have data about sections/labels in it that could be read and processed. Or of course, all necessary information is in the tex file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I have considered this, and it is possible I go back to that. But including the pdf gives a nice separation between stuff I wrote with coauthors for a journal and stuff I wrote myself for a thesis.

Comment: As far as I know TeX cannot have that kind of knowledge about the PDF it includes rather like how you can't 'get back' the `.tex` file from the PDF.

Comment: The alternative then if you can process the other files is to input (after suitable definitions) the `.toc` files generated for each to make the appendic TOC for your new document.